# Is there a way to retrieve the conversation history in Dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, chatbot, api-ai, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Is there a way to obtain the full conversation between the user and agent. Pretty much similar to what I get by clicking the history tag but programmatically. The point is to save the interaction between user and agent as text.

Thank you guys in advanced!

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 5):

There's no API to retrieve the history from Dialogflow directly. But what you can do is enable logging.

```
Agent Settings > General > Log Settings > Log interactions to Google Cloud
```

And all the interactions will be logged into Google Stackdriver, which has an API where you will be able to retrieve all the logs, and hence the chat history.

[https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/](http://Stackdriver%20Logging%20API)

This is how the logs are stored in Stackdriver

```
{
  insertId: "19ignahfzlu2o7"
  labels: {
    protocol: "V2BETA1"
    request_id: "3033c2e3-7cab-4a00-b2b7-207be8d22366"
    type: "dialogflow_request"
  }
  logName: "projects/dialogflowproject-ca57b/logs/dialogflow_agent"
  receiveTimestamp: "2019-03-27T12:44:42.547531753Z"
  resource: {
    labels: {
      project_id: "dialogflowproject-ca57b"
    }
    type: "global"
  }
  severity: "INFO"
  textPayload: "Dialogflow gRPC Request : session: projects / dialogflowproject - ca57b / agent / sessions / 53 d451c1 - 40 f5 - c00e - cbbd - 178e ff32b971 "
  query_params {
    time_zone: "America/Buenos_Aires"
  }
  query_input {
    text {
      text: "hi"
      language_code: "en"
    }
  }
  "  
  timestamp: "2019-03-27T12:44:42.420Z"
  trace: "53d451c1-40f5-c00e-cbbd-178eff32b971"
}
```

You can then retrieve the session from there, and build the whole chat history.

---

The other alternative is to save the interactions to a database when they are happening if the messages goes through your server first, which may not be your case.

Comment: is this free? because some google cloud features have to be pais for

Comment: Regarding the pricing, you can read this: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/audit-logging - But apparently is free for logs generated from Dialogflow. But I don't work for google, so you will need to ask them.