# For How long conversation history is maintained in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, history

We can see the conversation of user and bot in history tab, and see where bot understood and where it failed. Is there any way to download or save that history for analyses or later use. If we can't download that then how long that history is kept?

[Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377439/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-conversation-history-in-dialogflow) is for nodejs, i'm using .Net for backend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to retrieve the conversation history in Dialogflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377439/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-the-conversation-history-in-dialogflow)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is possible, but you can enable 'Log interactions to Google Cloud' in the Settings, then you can acces (also download) the events that occur during the conversation